# Angular Singleton Service With Componnets

Tags: angular

This is more of a structural question than bug related. I am writing an Angular application following the widely-used core, shared, and feature modules structure like the one [here](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter).
I too have a singleton notification service defined in the core module, except I use a custom component like the following to customize my notification:

```
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(
      SnackbarComponent,
      configuration
    );
```

and SnackbarComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: "snackbar",
  templateUrl: "./snackbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./snackbar.component.scss"]
})
export class SnackbarComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) {}
}
```

The thing I am confused about is where to put the declaration for this component.

1. If I put the declaration in the core module it won't be accessible to my feature modules (feature modules don't import core module, the core is only imported once and that's in the root module of application).
2. If I put the declaration in my shared module then my core module would have to import my shared module to access this component and that's contrary to the concept of the core module (not supposed to import the shared module).
3. Clearly putting my service in the shared module is not a good idea either as it is a singleton, and also I use this service in other core services (e.g. error interceptor).

Notice this is just an example, to illustrate the problem. I have a few other similar situations where my core services depend on components (a dialog service, a language service)

Any architectural advice to handle this is appreciated.

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: I think that you have to put the service in core module with providedIn root to make it singleton. for the component i don't see why you need it in the core module, i generally put only singleton services, interceptors, guards in the core module, no components

Comment: And where would the component be declared? Anywhere outside the core module, you put it you need to import the module containing it in the core module in order for the service to access it.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of thinking, one solution I came up with is to pass the component as an argument to the service:

```
open(component: SnackbarComponent) {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(
      component,
      configuration
    );
}
```

Not going to close the question as someone might have a better solution than mine.